# Generating new channel configtx

Tags: hyperledger-fabric

Getting 006 and 007 warnings when generating new channel configtx, I think I included the policy specifications already as shown below but it says no. I believe this results in permission error when I trying to generate the channel block.

```
2019-07-31 22:59:05.977 AEST [common.tools.configtxgen] doOutputChannelCreateTx -> INFO 005 Generating new channel configtx
2019-07-31 22:59:05.977 AEST [common.tools.configtxgen.encoder] NewChannelGroup -> WARN 006 Default policy emission is deprecated, please include policy specifications for the channel group in configtx.yaml
2019-07-31 22:59:05.978 AEST [common.tools.configtxgen.encoder] NewChannelGroup -> WARN 007 Default policy emission is deprecated, please include policy specifications for the channel group in configtx.yaml
2019-07-31 22:59:05.979 AEST [common.tools.configtxgen] doOutputChannelCreateTx -> INFO 008 Writing new channel tx
```

```
Channel: &ChannelDefaults
    # Policies defines the set of policies at this level of the config tree
    # For Channel policies, their canonical path is
    #   /Channel/
    Policies:
        # Who may invoke the 'Deliver' API
        Readers:
            Type: ImplicitMeta
            Rule: "ANY Readers"
        # Who may invoke the 'Broadcast' API
        Writers:
            Type: ImplicitMeta
            Rule: "ANY Writers"
        # By default, who may modify elements at this config level
        Admins:
            Type: ImplicitMeta
            Rule: "MAJORITY Admins"
    # Capabilities describes the channel level capabilities, see the
    # dedicated Capabilities section elsewhere in this file for a full
    # description
    Capabilities:
```

Getting below error creating channel block:

> [grpc] HandleSubConnStateChange -> DEBU 04b pickfirstBalancer:
>   HandleSubConnStateChange: 0xc00004fb10, READY 
> Error: got unexpected
>   status: FORBIDDEN -- implicit policy evaluation failed - 0
>   sub-policies were satisfied, but this policy requires 1 of the
>   'Writers' sub-policies to be satisfied: permission denied

Error from orderer container:

> [orderer.common.broadcast] ProcessMessage -> WARN 00e [channel:
>   examplechannel] Rejecting broadcast of config message from
>   173.20.0.10:36565 because of error: implicit policy evaluation failed - 0 sub-policies were satisfied, but this policy requires 1 of the 'Writers' sub-policies to be satisfied: permission denied

Comment: did you solve this issue? I am facing same thing

Answer (score 0):

I too face the similar issue,

From  Orderer logs :

```
2019-08-28 10:13:50.847 UTC [core.comm] ServerHandshake -> ERRO 016 TLS handshake failed with error tls: first record does not look like a TLS handshake server=Orderer remoteaddress=172.21.0.9:55802
2019-08-28 10:18:23.071 UTC [orderer.common.broadcast] ProcessMessage -> WARN 017 [channel: mychannel] Rejecting broadcast of config message from 172.21.0.9:55818 because of error: implicit policy evaluation failed - 0 sub-policies were satisfied, but this policy requires 1 of the 'Writers' sub-policies to be satisfied: permission denied
2019-08-28 10:18:23.071 UTC [comm.grpc.server] 1 -> INFO 018 streaming call completed grpc.service=orderer.AtomicBroadcast grpc.method=Broadcast grpc.peer_address=172.21.0.9:55818 grpc.code=OK grpc.call_duration=529.651µs
2019-08-28 10:18:23.074 UTC [common.deliver] Handle -> WARN 019 Error reading from 172.21.0.9:55816: rpc error: code = Canceled desc = context canceled
```

from CLI :

```
root@e36b98503955:/opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer# peer channel create -o orderer.example.com:7050 -c $CHANNEL_NAME -f ./channel-artifacts/channel.tx --tls true  --cafile $ORDERER_CA
2019-08-28 10:28:49.049 UTC [channelCmd] InitCmdFactory -> INFO 001 Endorser and orderer connections initialized
2019-08-28 10:28:49.493 UTC [common.tools.configtxgen.localconfig] Load -> INFO 002 Loaded configuration: /etc/hyperledger/fabric/configtx.yaml
2019-08-28 10:28:49.493 UTC [common.tools.configtxgen.encoder] NewChannelGroup -> WARN 003 Default policy emission is deprecated, please include policy specifications for the channel group in configtx.yaml
2019-08-28 10:28:49.494 UTC [common.tools.configtxgen.encoder] NewChannelGroup -> WARN 004 Default policy emission is deprecated, please include policy specifications for the channel group in configtx.yaml
Error: got unexpected status: BAD_REQUEST -- Attempted to include a member which is not in the consortium
```

From Native os

```
ravi@lab:~/hypldgr$ docker exec peer0.org1.example.com peer channel create -o orderer.example.com:7050 -c $CHANNEL_NAME -f ./channel-artifacts/channel.tx --tls true  --cafile $ORDERER_CA
2019-08-28 10:29:35.604 UTC [channelCmd] InitCmdFactory -> INFO 001 Endorser and orderer connections initialized
Error: got unexpected status: FORBIDDEN -- implicit policy evaluation failed - 0 sub-policies were satisfied, but this policy requires 1 of the 'Writers' sub-policies to be satisfied: permission denied
ravi@lab:~/hypldgr$
```

My Configtx.yml file:

```
    OneOrgsOrdererGenesis:
        <<: *ChannelDefaults
        Orderer:
            <<: *OrdererDefaults
            Organizations:
                - *OrdererOrg
            Capabilities:
                <<: *OrdererCapabilities
        Consortiums:
            SampleConsortium:
                Organizations:
                    - *Org1
    OneOrgsChannel:
        Consortium: SampleConsortium
        <<: *ChannelDefaults
        Application:
            <<: *ApplicationDefaults
            Organizations:
                - *Org1
            Capabilities:
                <<: *ApplicationCapabilities
```

Comment: So was this issue ever resolved? I am facing similar issue after upgrading from 1.4.1 to 1.4.4

Answer (score 0):

My issue has been resolved after changing the Channel name,  I used new channel name called 'mychannel1'

you can try and see if that resolves. It pushed me almost 2 days because of non-relevant error messages